# R - How to use sum and group_by inside apply?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, apply

I'm fairly new to R and I have the following issue.

I have a dataframe like this:

```
A | B | C | E | F |G 
1   02 XXX XXX XXX 1
1   02 XXX XXX XXX 1
2   02 XXX XXX XXX NA
2   02 XXX XXX XXX NA
3   02 XXX XXX XXX 1
3   Z1 XXX XXX XXX 1
4   02 XXX XXX XXX 2
....
M   02 XXX XXX XXX 1
```

The thing is that the dataframe possibly has 150k rows or more, and I need to generate another dataframe grouping by `A` (which is an ID) and count the following occurrences:

When B is 02 and G has 1      <- V 
When B is 02 and G is NA      <- W 
When B is Z1 and G has 1      <- X 
When B is Z1 and G is NA      <- Y 
Any other kind of occurrence   <- Z

For this simple example, the result should look something like this

```
A | V | W | X | Y | Z
1   2   0   0   0   0
2   0   2   0   0   0
3   1   1   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   1
...
M   1   0   0   0   0
```

At this point I managed to get the results using a for loop:

```
  get_counters <- function(df){
  
  counters <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 6, nrow = length(unique(df$A))))
  colnames(counters) <- c("A", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z")
  
  counters$A<- unique(df$A)
  
  for (i in 1:nrow(counters)) {
    counters$V[i] <- sum(df$A == counters$A[i] & df$B == "02" & df$G == 1, na.rm = TRUE)
    counters$W[i] <- sum(df$A == counters$A[i] & df$B == "02" & is.na(df$G), na.rm = TRUE)
    counters$X[i] <- sum(df$A == counters$A[i] & df$B == "Z1" & df$G== 1, na.rm = TRUE)
    counters$Y[i] <- sum(df$A == counters$A[i] & df$B == "Z1" & is.na(df$G), na.rm = TRUE)
    counters$Z[i] <- sum(df$A == counters$A[i] & (df$B == "Z1" | df$B == "02") & df$G!= 1, na.rm = TRUE)
  }
  
  return(counters)
}
```

Trying that on a small test dataframe returns all the correct results, but with the real data is extremely slow. I'm not sure how to use the `apply` functions, seems like a simple problem, but I have not found an answer. So far I've assumed that if I could use `apply` with the `sum` statement in my for loop (maybe using `group_by(A)`) I could do it, but I receive all kind of errors.

```
counters$V <- df%>%
                group_by(A)%>%
                sum(df$A == counters$A& df$B == "02" &df$G == 1, na.rm = TRUE)
```

> ```
> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
>   only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
> In addition: Warning message:
> In df$A== counters$A:
>   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
> ```

If I change the function to not use a for loop and not use `$` (I get an error referring to `"$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"`) I either get more errors or weird unreadable results (Large lists that contain more values that the original dataframe, huge empty matrices, etc...)

Is there a simple (maybe not simple but fast and efficient) way to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this very quickly using data.table.

Creating Dummy Data:

```
set.seed(123)
counters <- data.frame(A = rep(1:100000, each = 3), B = sample(c("02","Z1"), size = 300000, replace = T), G = sample(c(1,NA), size = 300000, replace = T))
```

All I am doing is counting the instances of the combination, then [reshaping](https://seananderson.ca/2013/10/19/reshape/) the data in the format you need:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(counters)
counters[,comb := paste0(B,"_",G)]
dcast(counters, A ~ comb, fun.aggregate = length, value.var = "A")
             A 02_1 02_NA Z1_1 Z1_NA
     1:      1    0     2    1     0
     2:      2    1     0    1     1
     3:      3    0     0    2     1
     4:      4    1     1    0     1
     5:      5    0     1    2     0
    ---                             
 99996:  99996    0     1    1     1
 99997:  99997    0     2    1     0
 99998:  99998    2     0    1     0
 99999:  99999    1     0    1     1
100000: 100000    0     2    0     1
```

I adopted a naming convention that is a bit more extensible (the new columns indicate what combination you are counting), but if you want to override, replace the `comb :=` line with four lines like the following:

```
counters[B == "02" & is.na(G), comb := "V"]
counters[B == "02" & !is.na(G), comb := "X"]
....
```

But I think the above is a bit more flexible.

Comment: You sir, are a genius, I've been struggling with this for a day or so, not only solved it  but gave me a wider range of options by automatically getting the possible combinations. Thank you very much!